# How to decrease the height of chooser (file-picker dialog)

Tags: dock, macos, file

My chooser (file-picker dialog) goes under the dock so I can't see buttons. What can I do?
[image]

Comment: If you hide the dock, can you access the bottom-right corner ?

Comment: I can see just a little bit of upper edge of buttons, but I can't access the corner.

Comment: Change the resolution might activate to resize all windows accordingly. So change resolution when 'chooser' is open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest method is to hold  <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>  & drag by any visible edge of the file-picker dialog. This will resize from all sides simultaneously.

Alternatively, for any open/save file-picker dialog which is not rendered as an attached sheet to the underlying window, you can resize from the top then drag the entire window up, or hold Option whilst resizing which will size from top & bottom simultaneously.

For an attached sheet, the only alternative appears to be to Esc from the file-picker, fullscreen the app, then open the file-picker again.
This will force the dialog to fit the window, allowing you to reach the bottom & resize upwards.

This size will then be remembered when not in fullscreen.

Comment: Yes it is 'open file' file-picker and yes fullscreen has helped. Thank you!

Comment: This answer does not work, as someone else claimed, on the New Image modal dialog on the Disk Utility app on a MacBook Air 11.  http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/219449/disk-utility-modal-dialog-opens-partially-off-screen

Comment: It behaves exactly the same way as any other, it just has a bigger lower section.