# Disk Utility modal dialog opens partially off-screen

Tags: macbook-pro, disk-utility, zoom

The New Image modal dialog in the Disk Utility application (on OS X 10.10.5) opens up with the Cancel button off the bottom of my MacBook Air 11's built-in display.  The green resize button, option resize, and option Window : Zoom don't bring it back on-screen.  How can I get the Cancel where I can see it to close the modal dialog, and/or do something else if another readable button appears to so allow?

Note that the answer to this question: [How to decrease the height of chooser (file-picker dialog)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151948/how-to-decrease-the-height-of-chooser-file-picker-dialog)
does not work with the Disk Utility New Image dialog on an MBA 11 (which appears to behave differently from a plain file-picker dialog).  ESC will close the window, but not allow you to actually see the Close button or any other useful buttons nearby for other operations.  Shift-drag-resize by mouse will expand but not shrink the New Image modal sheet enough on an MBA 11.  Making the Disk Utility window full-screen beforehand will not resize the New Image sheet to fit the MBA 11 display.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Did anyone actually try the answers in the so-called duplicate before voting to close?  If not, very bad form!

Comment: Given that @hotpaw2 has a pretty substantial rep here...  and has pointed out that the referenced "duplicate" does not address his question, I'd have to agree that this question is prematurely closed, and should be reopened.

Comment: It behaves exactly the same way as any other, it just has a bigger lower section. Did you try just dragging the parent window to the top of the screen?